# What determine how much time the query will cost?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, query-performance

I'm developer a system, and the database was not made for me. In the beginning all query of the database are super fast, because i don't have any data. Along the project the database grown, but the performance decreased. When the client access a page of the site, the system will require a page on database. As a user of web-browser, everybody wants that page load as soon as possible. But today this query is take like 7,5 seconds:

[image]

So my page will load my article, at last with 7,3 seconds minimum (This query was made with no users accessing the database, only me). For a web-user, this is a eternity.

I really wants know, what exactly causes the PostgreSQL take this time to get my query. I make my research, and some people say **the size of the database and the number of rows doesnt matter**. I know what's is B* and Hash Table, but i really don't know how to understand why it's taking 7 seconds to make a simple select.

This table has: 5,5 millions of rows. And the database is heavy (For me). 
[image]

And this is the PC. But i think the problem is not here. (Or maybe yes?)
[image]

What i want to understand what delay a query, like a simple select? Is the number of rows? The size of the tables?

[image]
[image]

```
 Seq Scan on article_article  (cost=0.00..1151560.85 rows=1 width=14) 
 (actual time=6727.343..6733.021 rows=1 loops=1)
    Filter: ((title)::text = 'Brazil'::text)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 5655059
  Planning time: 0.134 ms
  Execution time: 6733.050 ms
  (5 rows)
```

[image]

Comment: Please run the [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-explain.html) on your query. Next, copy the output into [this site](https://explain.depesz.com/). Finally, share the link to this post.

Comment: Also post the table and index definitions.

Comment: @ViniciusMorais The statement `..the size of the database and the number of rows  doesnt matter..` is not true. The difference can be (almost) imperceptible for the properly indexed tables - if indexes are suitable for queries. Otherwise the computational complexity grows linearly (best case) or even as power function (the case of joins on the number of tables).